# argument of type 'void (ClassName::)(QString&)' does not match 'void (ClassName::*)(QString&)'

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Im trying to use Qt's [qtconcurrentmap](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtconcurrentmap.html#map) to process some images and I'm getting the following error

```
argument of type 'void (ClassName::)(QString&)' does not match 'void (ClassName::*)(QString&)
```

I'm also getting

```
/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:: 
In member function 'bool QtConcurrent::MapKernel<Iterator, MapFunctor>::runIteration(Iterator, int, void*) 
[with Iterator = QList<QString>::iterator, MapFunctor = void (ClassName::*)(QString&)]':


/Library/Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Headers/qtconcurrentmapkernel.h:73: 
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 
'((QtConcurrent::MapKernel<QList<QString>::iterator, void (ClassName::*)(QString&)>*)this)->QtConcurrent::MapKernel<QList<QString>::iterator, void (ClassName::*)(QString&)>::map (...)'
```

This is my code

```
void ClassName::processImage(QString &f)
{

    Image image;
        image.read(qPrintable(f));
        try {
            //Apply effects on an Image
        } catch ( Magick::Exception & error) {
            // Displaying any possible errors on the text browser
            ui->textBrowser_error->setText(error.what());

        }
}



void ClassName::processAll() {

    foreach (QFileInfo f, list)
     {      QString str(f.absoluteFilePath());
            QList<QString> listof;
            listof.append(str);
     }


    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(listof, processImage);
}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things here. First, the variable `listof` is declared inside the `foreach` loop, so it may not be visible at the point of creating `future`. Second, you should use `&ClassName::processImage` as the second parameter to `QtConcurrent::map()`.

**UPDATE**:

Looking at the documentation, it seems you need to write the call to create the map this way:

```
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(listof, boost::bind(&ClassName::processImage, this));
```

(you have to use `boost.bind` to convert a member function into a normal function, that is what `map` expect as the second argument).

Comment: How could i have missed that? Great Answer!
Do you have any idea for the second error ?                    
   I'm still getting it

Comment: I think so. Looking at the documentation, the `map` method expects a function as the second parameter. Using a member function for this requires of `boost::bind`: `boost::bind(&ClassName::processImage, this)`.

Comment: Thats great Diego, No wonder why you've got 6 votes!
I get this error and I guess its because Im not using the boost library:
error: 'boost' has not been declared.
Isnt it ?

Comment: It is, you have to include `boost/bind.hpp`, if I remember it well out of my head.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's taking a function instead of a function address.

`QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::map(listof, &ClassName::processImage);`

Comment: Yes, to get a pointer to a non-static member function you must use `&Class::func` with the ampersand.

Answer (score 1):

About the second error: You can't pass a non-static member function like this. map() wouldn't know which object to call it on (which must be of type ClassName).

From QtConcurrentMap docs:

> QtConcurrent::map(), QtConcurrent::mapped(), and QtConcurrent::mappedReduced() accept pointers to member functions. The member function class type must match the type stored in the sequence: "

You pass a QString list, but the member function is from ClassName.
You can achieve something like this with boost::bind (and probably also with some mem_fun/bind1st-fu from the STL):

```
...map( listof, boost::bind( &ClassName::processImage, this, _1 ) );
```

Still this won't work as you can't call QTextEdit::setText() from other threads than the UI thread.

Also, it should be processImage(const QString&) instead of processImage(QString&).